# Hover effects ends before mouse is moved

Tags: html, css, hover

Does anyone have idea why hover effects ends before mouse is moved off an element?

I applied hover effect on before pseudo element.

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 0):

The `:hover` selector will complete once you hover over an element. Moving the mouse off of the element will stop/remove the effect. You should post in JSFiddle for more help. That way we can see what's going on.